# How to enter RAID config on ASUS P7P55-M motherboard?

Tags: raid, intel-matrix-storage

This motherboard is said to support `Intel Matrix Storage Technology Support RAID 0,1,0+1,5,10`

https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P7P55M/specifications/

I am not familiar with this technology.

Neither Ctrl-I nor Ctrl-H works on boot.

**UPDATE**

No any prompt to press Ctrl-I displayed

[image]

Comment: You have to go into the BIOS and enable RAID before you can configure it.

Comment: Of course I did.